# Get the current element?

Tags: reactjs

If I'm using something like this to set style:

```
<div style={this.setStyle()}>

  setStyle () {
    const style = {}
    if (this.state.fullScreen) {
      style.background = 'white'
      style.position = 'absolute'
      style.top = ???
    }
    return style
  }
```

How can I get the elements properties like `.offsetLeft` or `.scrollLeft` inside the funciton setStyle?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [refs](http://chenglou.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html#the-ref-attribute).

First, hook-up a `ref` attribute on your JSX element:

```
<div ref="myElement" style={this.setStyle()}>
```

Then, use this ref inside the `setStyle` method, to access the component's DOM node (the actual HTMLElement) `offsetLeft` or `scrollLeft` or anything else that you need.

```
setStyle () {
  // ...

  // this.refs.myElement is the DOM element
  const offsetLeft = this.refs.myElement.offsetLeft;

  return style;
}
```